# How can I verify an OAuth signature in Scala Play 2.4.X

Tags: scala, oauth, playframework, playframework-2.0

To integrate with a service, I need to implement REST endpoints on my Play 2.4 (scala) server. The service sends me a GET request signed with the key and secret they give me.

I need to verify that the requests are coming from them

My approach is:

```
val accessTokenOpt: Option[String] = request.headers.get(Security.AUTH_HEADER)
(accessTokenOpt, Security.consumer) match {
  case (Some(accessToken), Some(consumer)) => {
    val calculator = new OAuthCalculator(consumer, RequestToken("", ""))
    val expected = WS.url(s"http://${request.host}${request.uri}").sign(calculator)
    (expected.headers.get(Security.AUTH_HEADER), accessToken) match {
      case (Some(exp), Some(actual)) if exp == actual =>
        //good
      case (Some(exp), Some(actual)) =>
        //mismatch
      case (e, a) =>
        //missing tokens. :(
    }
  }
  case _ => //bad
}
```

problem is `expected.headers.(Security.AUTH_HEADER)` returns `None`

Am i missing something small in the code or is my entire approach wrong?

Comment: I guess it makes sense that I get a different signature since Im not using the same timestamp and nonce. how do i enrich the request that im about sign with these? Is my whole approach wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think that your approach is correct and the oauth signature, when calculated from the exact same parameters will always match. But you have to consider some parameters like nonce and timestamp as you mentioned and in order to do that, I had to work directly with the Java class that does the signature instead.

Here is how I managed to make it work. Keep in mind that in my case, the Authorization header that the external service that contacts my REST endpoint is sending contains all the information that was used to calculate the oauth_signature value, except for the oauth secret that I have.

```
private def getProtocolFromRequest[T](request: Request[T]): String = {
  // To handle the case where a SSL offloading is involved
  request.headers.get(HeaderNames.X_FORWARDED_PROTO) match {
    case Some(forwardedProto: String) => forwardedProto
    case _ => if(request.secure) "https" else "http"
  }
}

def isOAuthSignatureValid[T](request:  Request[T]): Boolean = {
  request.headers.get(com.ning.http.client.oauth.OAuthSignatureCalculator.HEADER_AUTHORIZATION) match {
    case Some(authorizationHeaders) =>
      val AuthRegex = ".*oauth_nonce=\"([^\"]*)\".*oauth_signature=\"([^\"]*)\".*oauth_timestamp=\"([^\"]*)\".*".r

      authorizationHeaders match {
        case AuthRegex(nonce: String, providedSignature: String, timestamp: String) =>
          val signatureCalculator = new OAuthSignatureCalculator(new com.ning.http.client.oauth.ConsumerKey(oauthKey, oauthSecret), new com.ning.http.client.oauth.RequestToken(null, ""))
          val params = request.queryString.map(query => new Param(query._1, query._2.head)).toSeq
          val protocol = getProtocolFromRequest(request)
          val url = s"$protocol://${request.host}${request.path}"

          val expectedSignature = signatureCalculator.calculateSignature(
            request.method,
            Uri.create(url),
            timestamp.toInt,
            nonce,
            new util.ArrayList(),
            scala.collection.JavaConversions.seqAsJavaList(params)
          )
          expectedSignature.equals(URLDecoder.decode(providedSignature, "UTF-8"))
        case _ => false
      }
    case _ => false
  }
}
```

The flow that worked for me is the following:

1. Grab the Authorization header
2. Create a OAuthSignatureCalculator by providing your oauth consumer key and secret. In my case I am not using any request token.
3. Extract the needed oauth parameters from the authorization headers: signature, nonce, timestamp
4. Use the OAuthSignatureCalculator to calculate a signature with the exact same nonce and timestamp
5. Compare the provided signature with the calculated one. If they match, the caller is authentified, otherwise, it's not.

Hopefully that can help somebody